# Postpone making custom target until install

Tags: cmake

I have something like this in my project:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT somefile)
add_custom_target(tgt ALL DEPENDS somefile)

install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/somefile DESTINATION somedir)
```

This works OK, but my command is being run during `make` because of `ALL` keyword in add_custom_target(). What i want is to make CMake to run this command only when `make install` is issued, not during build.

If i remove ALL keyword, whole target is not being built by default, so somefile is not produced and `make install` fails.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A possible solution is to have the `make install` command invoke the `make tgt` as a side effect. This can be done by using the `CODE` signature of the [install](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:install) command:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT somefile)
add_custom_target(tgt DEPENDS somefile)

install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND \"${CMAKE_COMMAND}\" --build \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}\" --target tgt)")
install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/somefile DESTINATION somedir)
```

The `execute_process` invokes cmake to build the target `tgt` before `somefile` is installed.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach does not work with Ninja on Windows due to: https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/issues/1132