# CMake add depedency to the install target

Tags: cmake

I've got the following problem using cmake. I use UseDoxygen from http://tobias.rautenkranz.ch/cmake/doxygen/ to generate the documentation for my library. This works fine, but know I want to realize the following: 
 When I call "make install" I want to build to Documentation and install it too. Therefore I add

```
install(DIRECTORY ${DOXYFILE_OUTPUT_DIR}/${DOXYFILE_HTML_DIR} DESTINATION share/doc/mylib/)
add_dependencies(install doc)
```

to my CMakeLists.txt. 
This results in an error:

```
  CMake Error at CMakeModules/UseDoxygen.cmake:145 (add_dependencies):
  add_dependencies Adding dependency to non-existent target: install
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:141 (include)
```

Is it possible to get a easy workaround for this? Because if the targets are not connected the install step installs nothing unless "make doc" is done manually befor calling "make install".

regards
Grisu

Comment: See the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636479/postpone-making-custom-target-until-install/8643015#8643015).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We build our documentation by adding it with `add_custom_target` with the `ALL` option specified so it builds with the `all` target.

Then to install, it's just the `install` command. There is no need to add anything to the `install` target.

If you add the documentation to the `all` target, then doing `make install` will also build the documentation.

Comment: This works fine. I achieved the right order ( documentation after build) using an additional add_dependencies.

Comment: This also works for other builtin targets such as `package` or `install`.

Comment: This is not an acceptable solution. The question remains unanswered, how to add a dependency to the install target only.

Comment: @andrewrk If you have a better answer, by all means post it. However, 7 years ago when this was asked and answered, this approach worked based on what was available in CMake and what we could accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

If you generate code documentation, isn't it a better idea to execute that command after the build command? In this way it will be available at install time.

You can add a custom command at POST_BUILD and execute the doxygen commands there. See more at http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:add_custom_command

Answer (score 2):

Building documentation via add_custom_target( ALL ...) is not an ideal solution, as it means the documentation gets built redundantly for all configurations (Debug, Release, RelWithDebInfo, MinSizeRel).

I'd like to build the documentation once regardless of the build config, then use the CONFIGURATIONS option of the install() command to install it only for the Release and RelWithDebInfo configs. install() should depend on the documentation target but, as I said, only build it for one config. There doesn't appear to be an way to add a dependency from install() onto the documentation that meets these requirements.