# Only install something in CMake if custom target is built

Tags: cmake

I'm currently trying to setup CMake to automatically generate my Doxygen documentation. I currently use the following code.

```
find_package(Doxygen)
if (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
    configure_file("docs/Doxyfile.in" "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile")
    add_custom_target(docs
                      COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE}
                              "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile"
                      SOURCES "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile")
    install(DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/docs/"
            DESTINATION "docs")
endif()
```

It works fine in when you enter `make docs` it generates the documentation in `PROJECT_BINARY_DIR/docs`. When you enter `make install` it copies the docs subdirectory to `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`. However when the user does not wish to generate documentation and just types `make install` the following error occurs:

```
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:36 (FILE):
  file INSTALL cannot find "/home/lukas/workspace/TheGame/build/docs".
```

How can one instruct the `install` command to only be executed if a custom target (`docs`) is built (or if the subdirectory `docs` exists in `PROJECT_BINARY_DIR`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried using the [OPTIONAL](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) flag?

```
install(DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/docs/" DESTINATION "docs" OPTIONAL)
```

Comment: This works, but is there really not a way to make it depend on a specific target?

Comment: @patrickvacek see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636479/postpone-making-custom-target-until-install for an alternate solution