# Reference the install target in CMake

Tags: cmake

How can I refer inside a CMake file the **install** target?

For example I want to do something like

```
add_custom_target(my-target DEPENDS install COMMAND my-target-command)
```

If I call

```
cmake --build . --target help
```

from CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR, in the returned list I can see there is target **install**.

Trying to

```
make my-target
```

with "Unix Makefiles" as generator results in an error

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `CMakeFiles/install.dir/all', needed by `CMakeFiles/my-target.dir/all'.  Stop.
```

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot refer to **install** target within `CMakeLists.txt`, it is internal for CMake. If you want to add actions to performed at *install stage*, use `install(CODE)` or `install(SCRIPT)` flows of [install() command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/install.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postpone making custom target until install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636479/postpone-making-custom-target-until-install)